# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'zxing'. Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, qr-code

I am trying to add gem 'zxing' into my project, but got this message after running the server

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'zxing'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/seas/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

any suggestion?

update:gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'devise'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'qrio'
gem 'jruby-jars' ,'>=0'
gem 'rake','~> 0.9.2'
gem 'rspec','~> 2.5.0'
gem 'zxing','~> 0.4.0'
```

I have tried to use 'qrio'before but the gem is not complete yet.

update2:after running bundle with --verbose

```
Using rake 0.9.6
0:  rake (0.9.6) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rake-0.9.6.gemspec
Using i18n 0.7.0
0:  i18n (0.7.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/i18n-0.7.0.gemspec
Using json 1.8.3
0:  json (1.8.3) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/json-1.8.3.gemspec
Using minitest 5.8.4
0:  minitest (5.8.4) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/minitest-5.8.4.gemspec
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
0:  thread_safe (0.3.5) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/thread_safe-0.3.5.gemspec
Using builder 3.2.2
0:  builder (3.2.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/builder-3.2.2.gemspec
Using erubis 2.7.0
0:  erubis (2.7.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/erubis-2.7.0.gemspec
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
0:  mini_portile2 (2.0.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/mini_portile2-2.0.0.gemspec
Using rack 1.6.4
0:  rack (1.6.4) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rack-1.6.4.gemspec
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
0:  mime-types-data (3.2016.0221) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/mime-types-data-3.2016.0221.gemspec
Using arel 6.0.3
0:  arel (6.0.3) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/arel-6.0.3.gemspec
Using execjs 2.6.0
0:  execjs (2.6.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/execjs-2.6.0.gemspec
Using bcrypt 3.1.11
0:  bcrypt (3.1.11) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32.gemspec
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
0:  debug_inspector (0.0.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/debug_inspector-0.0.2.gemspec
Using sass 3.4.21
0:  sass (3.4.21) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/sass-3.4.21.gemspec
Using byebug 8.2.2
0:  byebug (8.2.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/byebug-8.2.2.gemspec
Using chunky_png 1.3.5
0:  chunky_png (1.3.5) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/chunky_png-1.3.5.gemspec
Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
0:  coffee-script-source (1.8.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/coffee-script-source-1.8.0.gemspec
Using thor 0.19.1
0:  thor (0.19.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/thor-0.19.1.gemspec
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
0:  concurrent-ruby (1.0.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/concurrent-ruby-1.0.1.gemspec
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
0:  orm_adapter (0.5.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/orm_adapter-0.5.0.gemspec
Using diff-lcs 1.1.3
0:  diff-lcs (1.1.3) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/diff-lcs-1.1.3.gemspec
Using multi_json 1.11.2
0:  multi_json (1.11.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/multi_json-1.11.2.gemspec
Using jruby-jars 9.0.5.0
0:  jruby-jars (9.0.5.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/jruby-jars-9.0.5.0.gemspec
Using pg 0.18.4
0:  pg (0.18.4) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/pg-0.18.4-x86-mingw32.gemspec
Using bundler 1.11.2
0:  bundler (1.11.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/bundler-1.11.2.gemspec
Using rspec-core 2.5.2
0:  rspec-core (2.5.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rspec-core-2.5.2.gemspec
Using rspec-mocks 2.5.0
0:  rspec-mocks (2.5.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rspec-mocks-2.5.0.gemspec
Using tilt 2.0.2
0:  tilt (2.0.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/tilt-2.0.2.gemspec
Using rdoc 4.2.2
0:  rdoc (4.2.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rdoc-4.2.2.gemspec
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
0:  tzinfo (1.2.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/tzinfo-1.2.2.gemspec
Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
0:  nokogiri (1.6.7.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/nokogiri-1.6.7.2-x86-mingw32.gemspec
Using rack-test 0.6.3
0:  rack-test (0.6.3) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rack-test-0.6.3.gemspec
Using warden 1.2.6
0:  warden (1.2.6) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/warden-1.2.6.gemspec
Using mime-types 3.0
0:  mime-types (3.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/mime-types-3.0.gemspec
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.3.4
0:  autoprefixer-rails (6.3.4) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/autoprefixer-rails-6.3.4.gemspec
Using uglifier 3.0.0
0:  uglifier (3.0.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/uglifier-3.0.0.gemspec
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
0:  binding_of_caller (0.7.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/binding_of_caller-0.7.2.gemspec
Using qrio 0.0.1
0:  qrio (0.0.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/qrio-0.0.1.gemspec
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
0:  coffee-script (2.4.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/coffee-script-2.4.1.gemspec
Using sprockets 3.5.2
0:  sprockets (3.5.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/sprockets-3.5.2.gemspec
Using rspec-expectations 2.5.0
0:  rspec-expectations (2.5.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rspec-expectations-2.5.0.gemspec
Using zxing 0.4.0
0:  zxing (0.4.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/zxing-0.4.0.gemspec
Using sdoc 0.4.1
0:  sdoc (0.4.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/sdoc-0.4.1.gemspec
Using activesupport 4.2.5.1
0:  activesupport (4.2.5.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/activesupport-4.2.5.1.gemspec
Using tzinfo-data 1.2016.3
0:  tzinfo-data (1.2016.3) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/tzinfo-data-1.2016.3.gemspec
Using loofah 2.0.3
0:  loofah (2.0.3) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/loofah-2.0.3.gemspec
Using mail 2.6.4
0:  mail (2.6.4) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/mail-2.6.4.gemspec
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.6
0:  bootstrap-sass (3.3.6) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6.gemspec
Using rspec 2.5.0
0:  rspec (2.5.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rspec-2.5.0.gemspec
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
0:  rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3.gemspec
Using globalid 0.3.6
0:  globalid (0.3.6) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/globalid-0.3.6.gemspec
Using activemodel 4.2.5.1
0:  activemodel (4.2.5.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/activemodel-4.2.5.1.gemspec
Using jbuilder 2.4.1
0:  jbuilder (2.4.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/jbuilder-2.4.1.gemspec
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
0:  rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3.gemspec
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
0:  rails-dom-testing (1.0.7) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7.gemspec
Using activejob 4.2.5.1
0:  activejob (4.2.5.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/activejob-4.2.5.1.gemspec
Using activerecord 4.2.5.1
0:  activerecord (4.2.5.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/activerecord-4.2.5.1.gemspec
Using actionview 4.2.5.1
0:  actionview (4.2.5.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/actionview-4.2.5.1.gemspec
Using actionpack 4.2.5.1
0:  actionpack (4.2.5.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/actionpack-4.2.5.1.gemspec
Using actionmailer 4.2.5.1
0:  actionmailer (4.2.5.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/actionmailer-4.2.5.1.gemspec
Using railties 4.2.5.1
0:  railties (4.2.5.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/railties-4.2.5.1.gemspec
Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
0:  sprockets-rails (3.0.4) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/sprockets-rails-3.0.4.gemspec
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
0:  coffee-rails (4.1.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/coffee-rails-4.1.1.gemspec
Using responders 2.1.2
0:  responders (2.1.2) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/responders-2.1.2.gemspec
Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
0:  jquery-rails (4.1.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/jquery-rails-4.1.1.gemspec
Using rails 4.2.5.1
0:  rails (4.2.5.1) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/rails-4.2.5.1.gemspec
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
0:  sass-rails (5.0.4) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/sass-rails-5.0.4.gemspec
Using web-console 2.3.0
0:  web-console (2.3.0) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/web-console-2.3.0.gemspec
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
0:  turbolinks (2.5.3) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/turbolinks-2.5.3.gemspec
Using devise 3.5.6
0:  devise (3.5.6) from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/devise-3.5.6.gemspec
Bundle complete! 20 Gemfile dependencies, 71 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: Can you show the Gemfile here?

Comment: bundler seem to supressed the orginal error message. try running bundler with the flag '--verbose'

Comment: I have tried --verbose and get message above.please take a look

Answer (score 0):

`gem 'zxing'` depends on `MRI (1.8.7 and 1.9.2)` but your ruby version `2.2.0`. Change your ruby version to `1.9.2` to have this feature.

Comment: but I installed this gem in ruby `2.2.1`

Comment: That is great. What did you follow to install it? I just refering from the repo https://github.com/ecin/zxing.rb

Comment: The usual way to do it, `$ gem install zxing` or `gem 'zxing'`

Comment: @NoFace01. Please change your ruby version and change the spec in Gemfile with gem 'zxing' and run `bundle install`.

Comment: I have change the ruby version but error still exist,any help, PS.I use railsinstaller from railsinstaller.com newest version

Comment: are you using windows for rails development?

Comment: yes, windows.....I have change the ruby version but error still exist, I'm very new to rails,so I might did it wrong,let me remind what I did. first of all,I use railsinstaller from railsinstaller.com,newest version,Ruby 2.2.4,Rails 4.2.Then I add "gem 'zxing'" in gemfile.Then bundle install.Then I add "require 'zxing'" in my_controller.then run server and got that error.

Comment: Is bundle install success?

Comment: I think it is windows problem. I myself never use windows for rails development. Lots of dependency out there and It doesn't work properly. I suggest you to move in linux distribution like ubuntu or centos for rails development. You can use cloud9 for rails development as remote.

Comment: yes,it is,the error occur after i add require 'zxing' and run server

Comment: OK,If will reinstall all about ruby on rails,and try it all again .If it still not work maybe I might move to linux instead

Comment: That is better. You can try with ruby 1.9.2 at least in windows. If it is working then you can continue working in windows otherwise you have no choice but move to linux. I think this is the best option. Thank you